# Once distances between users are known, how can the users be sorted underneath one another by "distanceToCurrentLoggedInUser"?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

So all users have 3 info fields. Users are displayed underneath each other. I want them sorted via distance (which is not one of the 3 field). I calculated the distances successfully and get:

```
1811862.740066788 distance
6430346.406366229 distance
6430346.406366229 distance
6430346.406366229 distance
1811862.740066788 distance 
6430346.406366229 distance
```

These don't display as sorted from small too big. I think I need to use something like: self.peopl.sort(by .........

I tried to use this:

```
self.peopl.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
return Unicode.CanonicalCombiningClass(rawValue: UInt8(p1.distance!)) < Unicode.CanonicalCombiningClass(rawValue: UInt8(p2.distance!))
    })
    self.table.reloadData()
     }
```

Relevant code that produced distance results.

```
for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
if people.key != thisUsersUid {
let peopleObject = people.value as? [String: AnyObject]
let peopleEducation = peopleObject?["Education"] as? String
let peopleWhatIamConsideringBuying = peopleObject?["WhatIamConsideringBuying"] as? String
let peoplePhotoPosts = peopleObject?["PhotoPosts"] as? String
let peopleimageDownloadURL = peopleObject?["imageDownloadURL"] as? String
...........
let distance = locCoord.distance(from: self.locCoord1)
print(distance, "distance")
let peopl = Userx(Education: peopleEducation, WhatIamConsideringBuying: peopleWhatIamConsideringBuying, PhotoPosts: peoplePhotoPosts, imageDownloadURL: peopleimageDownloadURL, .........., distance:distance)
self.people.append(peopl)
}
self.peopl.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
return Unicode.CanonicalCombiningClass(rawValue: UInt8(p1.distance!)) < Unicode.CanonicalCombiningClass(rawValue: UInt8(p2.distance!))
})
self.table.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: self.peopl.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
return p1.distance < p2.distance
})

Comment: Then it gives error: Cannot convert value of type 'Double?' to expected argument type 'Unicode.CanonicalCombiningClass' That is why I got to the Unicode segment of code? Also, does p1 not need to be replaced with locCoord and p2 locCoord1? Thanks for your time.